# Select 2 date range within the selected month (datepicker)

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I have to input field "From" and "to

```
<input type="text" name="startDate" id="from" size="12"/>
<input type="text" name="endDate" id="to" size="12"/>
```

If would like to know how I could make in sort that datepicker block the calendar within the month where From is selected. So if I choose November 20th, then the id "to" could only be after the 20th to 31st of november. It can't go to the other month.

Here's what I have

```
var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: false,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            maxDate: '+0D',
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                    instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings );
                dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            }
        });
```

How could we block the user to not go pass the month selected?

Comment: Is it only a typo in the question or do you have `<input type="text" name="endDate" id="from" size="12"/>` in your code as well? Because the id is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a date range picker like this one: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/